# How to test my Exception extension method that uses DbEntityValidationException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I hope I’m just over looking something really simple…

The answer I need must provide a test that uses Moq due to the fact that I don’t have access to Fakes for my personal MSDN (professional). Only premium and ultimate can use Fakes. The unit test must be able to run without access to any external resources. No connecting to a SQL database with an Entity Framework DbContext.

```
public static string ToDetailedString(this Exception ex)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    AddExceptionToBuilder(builder, ex);
    return builder.ToString();
}

private static void AddExceptionToBuilder(StringBuilder builder, Exception ex)
{
    builder.Append(builder.Length > 0 ? "\r\n" + ex.Message : ex.Message);

    var validationException = ex as DbEntityValidationException;
    if (validationException != null)
    {
        foreach (var detail in validationException.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(error => error.ValidationErrors))
        {
            builder.Append("\r\n" + detail.PropertyName + " : " + detail.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        AddExceptionToBuilder(builder, ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

Here is why it’s so difficult to test. It’s not as simple as just creating a new DbEntityValidationException because you have to pass in a list of DbEntityValidationResult. You cannot instantiate a DbEntityValidationResult without providing a DbEntityEntry. The only way I’ve found to create an DbEntityEntry is to get it from DbContext.Entry(). This means you must have a valid DbContext that needs access to a database.

This is the only code I've been able to make work but it requires access to a database.

```
/// <summary>
/// This test method must be ran against the database. I cannot figure out a way to create an entry without
/// a valid context to a real database?
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void ToDetailStringForDbEntityValiditionException()
{
    if (!TestHelper.RunUnitTestAgainstDatabase)
    {
        return;
    }

    var errors = new List<DbValidationError>();
    errors.Add(new DbValidationError("Username", Constants.UsernameLengthError));

    var context = new EntityFrameworkRepository();
    var entry = context.Entry(new User());
    var results = new List<DbEntityValidationResult>();
    var result = new DbEntityValidationResult(entry, errors);
    results.Add(result);

    var exception = new DbEntityValidationException("Registration Failed.", results);

    var expected = "Registration Failed.\r\nUsername : " + Constants.UsernameLengthError;
    var actual = exception.ToDetailedString();

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?  I have a similar problem where I'm trying to test against DbEntityValidationException and I can't due to the internal constructors.  MS devs seem to be using an internal class of some sort for their own testing but god forbid they expose it to the rest of the world:  https://github.com/Icehunter/entityframework/blob/master/test/EntityFramework/UnitTests/Internal/TestHelpers/InternalEntityEntryForMock.cs

Comment: I still do not have a good solution for this. Right now I'm just converting the exception to a long string and ensuring the message details contain "valid" information. Still looking for a better solution but right now it's all I got.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, using the Entity Model and Connection I had already setup:

```
var context = new DbContext("name = JobManagerConnection");
var entry = context.Entry(new Models.JobManager.Job());
var errInner = new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError("Test Property", "Test Message");
var lstErrInner = new List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError> { errInner };
var errOuter = new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult (entry, lstErrInner);
var lstErrOuter = new List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult> { errOuter };
throw new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException("Test Data Exception", lstErrOuter);
```